# Select/DropDownList mis-displaying

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two drop-down lists on my page but what I notice is when data is loaded via JavaScript in to any of the two, the display is screwed up. Instead of actually dropping down when click, my drop-down list also drops up and disappears into the top of the page.How do I fix this problem please?

```
     <asp:Panel ID="Pnlclone" runat="server" >
                            <div class="module-row">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblClone"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td> 
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="sRole" CssClass="scrollable" runat="server"  Width="250px" Height="23px">
                                                </asp:DropDownList> 
                                        </td>
                                        <td> 
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="sUsers"  CssClass="scrollable" runat="server" Width="250px" Height="23px">
                                                </asp:DropDownList> 
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="btnCancel" runat="server" value="Cancel" type="button" />
                                            <input id="btnsubmit" runat="server" value="Clone" type="button" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've got too much data to display in the dropdown.

Is this a straight HTML forms dropdown or a third-party control?

Comment: It is an ASP.NET Dropdownlist control. I mean it works fine everywhere else on the same form. Only that the particular two do not seem to display correctly.